# Reading lines from each file in an array -- condition never succeeds

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, for-loop, cat

I'm trying to integrate a cat command into a for loop with the cat reading the element '$currentccoutput' but it seems (I think) that cat is reading the line literally rather than understanding that it's an array element with the name of a txt file.

```
#create an array of text files

currentccoutputs=($currentccfolder'/'*.txt*)

#basic for loop until I can get my cat command working

for currentccoutput in "${currentccoutputs[@]}"; do

    cat "$currentccoutput" | while read LINE; do

        # I have .txt files with three numbers per line
        # that I would like to read / use

        IFS=' ' read C1 C2 threshold
            if [ $C1 != $C2 ] && [ $threshold \> 0.2 ]; then
            echo "Huzzah!!!! Progress at last"
        fi

     done < "$currrentccoutput" # I don't know what 
                                # this backwards chevron
                                # does but other people
                                # have used it...
done
```

I've no doubt there are other imperfections with this snippet but I'm entirely new to creating scripts so I'm trying to keep things within the realms of what I know for now and hopefully sophisticated solutions will come later. *(for now, I'm trying to get from island A to island B, where a few bits of wood and some hemp rope will be both understood and replicable. Whilst I appreciate advice on - and hope one day to build - a decent frigate, right now it might leave me somewhat confused).*

I've never even used 'while' 'read' or 'LINE', I've pinched it from someone else's solution.

I have used the echo command to ensure it's not my paths that are wrong, just that I'm not using cat correctly.

Comment: `cat "$currentccoutput" |` and `< "$currentccoutput"` both claim to redirect the loop's stdin. There's only one stdin, so they can't both take effect. (Also, you should use the `<` form only; it's far more efficient, and doesn't cause a subshell to be spawned with the variable-scoping impact that implies).

Comment: You are trying to pipe the output of `cat` to a `while` loop that has its `stdin` redirected to a file.

Comment: That said, note that piping into a `while read` loop causes its own bugs; see [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: ...you might want to also run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- and note that `[ "$threshold" '>' 0.2 ]` does a *string* comparison, not a *numeric* comparison; for a floating-point numeric comparison, you need to use different tools like `bc`

Comment: BTW, with respect to the `while read` idiom, there's detailed documentation on it in [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy could you expand on what you what you mean by only using the `<` form? Do i just replace the  `cat "$currentccoutput" | ` with the  `< "$currentccoutput" ` and delete the final `< "$currrentccoutput"` that I've put after my `done`?

Comment: So Far: Removing the lower `< "$currentccoutput"` seems to have worked but as has already pointed out I'm not making a numerical comparison for the second argument in my `if` statement ( i.e. `[ "$threshold" '>' 0.2 ]` ). I've tried to use `| bc -l` but it's not working. Presumably, this is something I can fix easily?

Comment: BTW, this would be a better-asked question if you'd tried to take the array out of the picture -- if you'd tested with `currentccoutput=whatever.txt` instead of a `for` loop over an array at all, that would have dispelled the impression that there was some kind of interaction between those features before the question got asked in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem with how you're using `cat` is that you're overriding it with a (much better) shell-builtin redirection. That fine -- in fact, it's *preferable*; you shouldn't use `cat` unless you absolutely must.<sup>[1]</sup>

What *is* a problem is that you're running `read LINE` and then `read C1 C2 threshold` after each other, both coming from the same source.

This means that you read the *first* line of each file into the variable `LINE` (which your code never looks at again), and the *second* line into the variables `C1`, `C2` and `threshold`. If there are more lines, you read the third into `LINE`, the fourth into `C1`/`C2`/`threshold`, etc.

If you don't *want* to skip every other line (starting at the first one), just take out the `read LINE` entirely, making your code something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in '') echo "ERROR: This script must be run with bash" >&2; exit 1;; esac

currentccoutputs=( "$currentccfolder"/*.txt )

for currentccoutput in "${currentccoutputs[@]}"; do
    while IFS=$' \t\r' read -r c1 c2 threshold; do
        if [ "$c1" != "$c2" ] && [ "$(bc -l <<<"$threshold > 0.2")" = 1 ]; then
            echo "Huzzah!!!! Progress at last: c1=$c1; c2=$c2; threshold=$threshold"
        fi
     done < "$currentccoutput"
done
```

See:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*
- [BashFAQ #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022) - *How can I calculate with floating point numbers instead of just integers?* (describing the `bc` idiom used above)
- [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) - *I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?* (describing why `cat | while read` is a Bad Idea)

---

<sub>[1] - Yes, this means you should ignore many if not most of the examples of bash code you find online. [Sturgeon's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law) applies.</sub>

Comment: This works! I cannot thank you enough for helping me as well as providing further links. The editing path I had descended down was not going to take me anywhere.

Comment: Excellent footnote!  I would generalize a bit more and say you should ignore many if not most of the online examples for any language.